# Flutter Apple silicon fatal Shared_preferences error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I am using an Apple Silicon mac for my Flutter project and I have an issue after passing my program to my new computer.

```
Xcode's output:
↳
In file included from /Users/gorkem/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+4/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/gorkem/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+4/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 1 but produced no further output
    CompileC /Users/gorkem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ghjviwzylhbejhfsayqxcrbfzwyc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/local_auth.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.o /Users/gorkem/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'vibration' from project 'Pods')
```

I think that the problem comes from the file flutter.h inside the shared preferences package.
Here's one of the part of the problem. If you need more, I can edit it anytime.
I already did many things related to this issue but apparently, it didn't work. If you have a recommendation, I'l listen to it.
BTW, I tried `flutter clean` and then rerun, tried to update all the packages. None of them work.

Comment: Same problem here with the M1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing CocoaPod from your project

```sh
cd ios
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
flutter run
```

If this doesn't work try reinstalling flutter or switch to beta channel