# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found running on MabookBook M1

Tags: flutter

I already tried all of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios) and nothing

Xcode build done.                                            4,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[22045]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1ffbaf8f0) and ?? (0x11b1602b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[22045]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1ffbaf940) and ?? (0x11b160308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/netolobo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.28/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/netolobo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.28/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.


Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-13.0.pre.499, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-arm, locale pt-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: me too! after digging the web for a solution, I changed to flutter beta, and it did the trick! `flutter channel beta`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389893/4465386

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the final solution!

Backup ios/Runner folder.

Delete the ios folder.

Run **flutter create .** in the previous folder where you have your project(cd users/user/"projects_folder") (this will recreate your ios folder).

Paste your Runner backup in the ios folder (into the project).

Open Runner.xcworkspace (into ios folder) and there, check the Version, the Bundle ID, all the info.

(If do you Have Firebase, you have to copy and paste again the Google Service-Info.Plist into the Runner folder (Always through Xcode) (If do you do this manually, it doesn't work).

Finally, **flutter run** and should work!